# np.loadtxt files syntax issues

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a bar plot in python by reading in a csv file. I've done this before with box plots so I know that the way I'm trying works in some capacity; however, I'm having issues with it this time. I've tried everything I can think of. I only need to use the first 6 columns (0-5) and need to skip the first row. Here is my line of code:

`file = np.loadtxt('Finalprojectdata.csv', delimiter = ',', skiprows=1, usecols = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))`

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LvFM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dtype` parameter of the `loadtxt` function and set its value to `str`.

```
file = np.loadtxt(
    'Finalprojectdata.csv', 
    dtype=str, 
    delimiter = ',', 
    skiprows=1, 
    usecols = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)
```